# Saving outputs of "proccesing" to temp file in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to save the output of a "proccesing" algorithm executed in PyQGIS as a temporal file, and then re-using it with another algorithm. The desired result is to write the output only at the end of the script. I'm working in QGIS 3.2.

```
 
    from qgis.core import * 
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    import processing
```

path='path/to/output/'

parameters = { '-u' : False, 
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '',
'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '',
'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 100,
'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : '565000,600000,6220000,6240000 [EPSG:32721]',
'distance' : 0.5, 'exponent' : 0.5, 'flat' : 0, 'high' : 255,
'output' : path + 'rast.tif', 'seed' : None }

processing.run('grass7:r.random.surface', parameters)

parameters = { 'GRID_IN' : path + 'rast.tif',
'GRID_OUT' : path + 'rast_reclas_v1.sdat',
'LOOKUP' : [0,150,0,151,255,1], 'METHOD' : 2 }

processing.run('saga:reclassifyvaluessimple', parameters)

parameters = { 'COPY_SUBDATASETS' : False,
'DATA_TYPE' : 5,
'INPUT' : path + 'rast_reclas_v1.sdat',
'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '',
'OUTPUT' : path + 'rast_v1.tif',
'TARGET_CRS' : 'EPSG:32721' }

processing.run('gdal:translate', parameters)

Comment: I´m dumb at Python, but whem you export a model as python script, it creates the output just like "'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT".
Then the next step has an input as 'INPUT': outputs['stepName']['OUTPUT'].
Maybe you should look there.